# Error while creating a UDF in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I’m trying to create a `UDF` in Spark using the following code

```
val makeSIfTesla = udf {(make: BigInt) => if(make == 0) 1 else make}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported
```

Why?

Comment: 1 is an integer and make is a BigInt. make them both the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you are returning `1` as an Integer. Also, `bigint` in hive is actually a `Long`. So your `else` is returning  `Long` and your `if` is returning a `Int` which makes the return type of your UDF `Any` which isn't supported by Spark DataFrame. [Here's a list of supported datatypes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/package-summary.html)

If you use `df.schema`, it'll show you that what you actually need is `LongType`

```
val df = sqlContext.sql(" select cast(2 as bigint) as a ")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: bigint]

df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- a: long (nullable = false)


df.schema
// res16: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(a,LongType,false))
```

Your UDF should look something like:

```
val makeSIfTesla = udf {(make: Long) => if(make == 0) 1.toLong else make}
//makeSIfTesla : UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,LongType,List(LongType))
```

However, for something as simple as this, you really don't need a UDF. You can use the `when-otherwise` construct available in Spark.

```
df.withColumn("x" , when($"x" === lit(0) , lit(1) ).otherwise($"x") )
```

where `x` is the column you are passing to your UDF `makeSIfTesla`.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the code like below:

```
val makeSIfTesla = udf {(make: BigInt) => if(make == 0) BigInt(1) else make}
```

The problem was that `1` is `Int`, and `make` is `BigInt`, so the method in the udf was returning `Any`. `Any` is not supported with udf function and hence the error you see. Making the type consistent makes the method return `BigInt` and fixes the issue. You can also make `make`'s type `Int`

Comment: i changed the code like ur answer. And then i got another error:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.math.BigInt is not supported

Comment: @RyanWang - try changing to `long`?